# Can I simply state that this subset of a metric space is a path by inspection?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> In the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^2, d^{(2)})$ and for any $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$, let $L_x$ be the straight-line segment joining the point $(1, 1)$ to the point $(x, 0)$, so $L_x =$ {$(x(1 − t) + t, t) : t ∈ [0, 1]$}.
>
> Prove that for each $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$, $L_x$ is $d^{(2)}_{L_x}$-connected.

**My answer:**

$L_x$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a straight line segment and therefore by inspection a path.  This means that $\left(L_x,d^{(2)}_{L_x}\right)$ is path-connected for any $x∈\mathbb{R}$ and it follows that $\left(L_x, d^{(2)}_{L_x}\right)$ is connected for any $x∈\mathbb{R}$.

My question is can I simply state that is a path by inspection or do I need to be more rigorous about it?

Comment: 'By inspection' generally means the statement is verifiable by plugging in a few values into some equations. This isn't the case here. I think a more rigorous proof is required.

Comment: Well from the definition $L_x$ is quite clearly a path; it's (the image of) the path
$$[0,1]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{R}^2:\ t\ \longmapsto\ (x(1-t)+t,t).$$

Comment: I don't see that much more rigor is even possible.  You can note that $(x(1-t)+t, t)$ is a continuous $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ function; what else can you say?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  If more rigor isn't possible is there a better way of wording it instead maybe?  Such as Servaes comment or something similar.  I'm trying to get into the habit of answering questions as succinctly as possible while still ensuring I receive as many marks as possible for upcoming exams.  This question was worth 2 marks I should add.

Comment: Also I was under the impression that by inspection meant you could tell just be looking.

Comment: I would take "by inspection" to mean more or less "self-evident" (with all the potential for abuse that that entails).  I would use it with caution; I think it is warranted in this case (though the course context is authoritative), but it should only be used when any evidence would tend to obscure rather than clarify the truth of the assertion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you said is fine, but if it makes you feel better, you can note that it is the image of $[0,1]$ under the continuous map $[0,1]\ni t\mapsto x(1-t)+t\in \mathbb{R}^2$, and is hence connected.